# App images not loading intermittently

Tags: image, facebook, caching

We have a "Shop" application that intermittently fails to load images. It worked perfectly for months, and without change, it started doing this. If you click through page navigation at the bottom, once in a while product images will load correctly.

Our server is responding with images every time, but for some reason Facebook is not loading them consistently. In addition, the links do not work correctly when the images fail.

Is this a temporary problem with Facebook, or is there something we might be doing wrong?

Comment: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net

Comment: seriously?  what is with the down votes?  the guy is simply asking "Is this a temporary problem with Facebook, or is there something we might be doing wrong?"  and you point him to a bug tracking page?

Comment: Hi. I voted to close this question because questions on stackOverflow should be related to implementation questions, and not service availability. There are numerous other places you should look for that answer: the bug tracker, the live status page, and the facebook developers group on facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you're requesting images correctly

`<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture" />` will give you founder of Facebook

[image]

Comment: The images are served from our own domain, but it seems Facebook is filtering the IFRAME content inconsistently.

Comment: I stand corrected, the tab was set to FBML and not IFRAME.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming its an FBML Application, since this would never happen in an IFRAME application

FBML Apps experience problems from time to time, so if you value your application, you should start planning for an IFRAME conversion

Comment: It is an IFRAME application, and the image tags intermittently don't appear at all. The images are not even served from Facebook. I wasn't sure if there was an implementation/configuration option we might be missing, or if we should just chalk it up to bugs in Facebook.